# How do I make a list of numbers by tenths?

Tags: r

I know that 1:10 will give me a vector of all integers from 1 to 10, but how can I get numbers from 1 to 2 going up by tenths (i.e., 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, ..., 2.0)?

Comment: For more info, type ?seq into the console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `seq`

```
> seq(1, 2, by = 0.1)
 [1] 1.0 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 2.0
```

Comment: but beware FAQ 7.31: `x <- seq(1,2,by=0.1); x[2]-1==0.1` is `FALSE`

Comment: @BenBolker, but that's not really a problem with `seq` and rather a problem with floating point arithmetic, right?

Comment: yes -- I was just warning the OP in advance, figuring there was some probability that they would fall into the trap.

Comment: @BenBolker, a high probability, for sure, but is there a reasonable alternative other than to "just don't be surprised when `0.1 != 0.1`; maybe try `all.equal` instead"? (I'm genuinely interested, by the way, and appreciate your comment and foresight for what is typical use).

Comment: The only thing I can think of offhand is that it's often a good idea to iterate over integers and then modify the variables, e.g. `for (i in 10:20) { x <- i/10 ; ... }` rather than `for (x in seq(1,2,by=0.1)) { ... }` (i.e., do integer arithmetic & comparisons where possible.  That said, the latter seems more readable to me.

Answer (score 4):

Just in the spirit of there is more than one way to do things, another option is:

```
> (10:20)/10
 [1] 1.0 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 2.0
```